# Create certain array with fetch

Tags: php, sql

I normally use fetch_assoc to fetch, but for this case I kind of need an array fetched in this way, but I don't know how.

I have two tables called 'grades' with grades and information of the grade and 'subjects' with subjects. I need to sort them like this:

```
$result = [
    ['English' =>
        [0 => '9', 1 => '10', 2 => '4'],
        [0 => 'test1', 1 => 'essay1', 2 => 'test2']
    ]
    ['Maths' =>
        [0 => '9', 1 => '10', 2 => '4'],
        [0 => 'test1', 1 => 'exercise 1', 2 => 'test2']
    ]
];
```

Subjects are English and Maths, the first array is grades and the second is information. I just don't know how I could make it that it is sorted like this without doing multiple queries.

Comment: If you want it to be done in the SQL part then add the table scheme (and if that the case you can remove the PHP tag)

Comment: I didn't know which way was the best. I'll look into it for a moment.

Comment: If you want it to be done in the PHP level - please attach example input and output of the array after they fetch from the SQL